# Is it possible to accept PayPal payments in a iframe (US based e-commerce)?

Tags: iframe, paypal

I have a client who is asking for receiving payments with PayPal inside a iframe in e-commerce. The problem is that I'm not sure if this is possible. The "Hosted Solution" [1] is not supported in US and my client is US based.

The nearest solution seems to be "In-Context Checkout in Express Checkout" [2], which opens a popup on checkout. Is there any alternative for this which uses an iframe in my checkout page?

[1] https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/
[2] https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at The PayPal Payments Advanced product, which displays the credit card form in an iFrame along with a "Pay with PayPal" button. you can read about it here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced/